# discord py в цикле не меняется embed

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, while

Делаю розыгрыш в боте и столкнулся с проблемой то, что он изменяет текст один раз, а надо, что бы изменял embed до конца розыгрыша каждые 2 секунды, **не изменяется только embed**

```
    con = connect["time"]
    
    while connect["time"] != 0:
        
        embed = discord.Embed( title = f"""
Победитель получит: {text}
Победителей: {win}
Секунды: {connect["time"]} | Минуты: {round(connect["time"] / 60)} | Часа: {round(connect["time"] / 60 / 60)}
        """, colour = 0xe821f8 )

        await message.edit( embed = embed )
        con -= 2
        
        winer.update_one( {"guild": ctx.guild.id}, {"$set": {"time": con}} )
        await asyncio.sleep(2)
```

вот часть кода

Answer (score 0):

Из кода не выяснил, устанавливаете ли вы переменной `message` само сообщение или как.

Но лично у меня всё заработало с подобным кодом:

```
@client.command()
async def test(ctx):
    con = 10
    embed = discord.Embed( title = f"""
Победитель получит: {random.randint(1,100)}
Победителей: {random.randint(1,100)}
Секунды: {random.randint(1,100)} | Минуты: {random.randint(1,100)} | Часа: {random.randint(1,100)}
        """, colour = 0xe821f8 )
    message = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    while con != 0:
        embed = discord.Embed( title = f"""
Победитель получит: {random.randint(1,100)}
Победителей: {random.randint(1,100)}
Секунды: {random.randint(1,100)} | Минуты: {random.randint(1,100)} | Часа: {random.randint(1,100)}
        """, colour = 0xe821f8 )
        await message.edit( embed = embed )
        con -= 1
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
```

Прошу также обратить внимание что я убрал код для *pymongo* и заменил во всех эмбедах всё на рандомные числа ради примера, по своему опыту знаю что иногда *mongodb* не выводит ошибку, перепроверьте код, удалив код для *pymongo*, или же перепроверьте, устанавливаете ли вы переменную `message`, а именно: `message = await ctx.send(embed=embed)`